# Sub sites under main site

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I want to create a site in Drupal 7, which has admin user under this main site.

I want to create 3 sub sites whose links I am going to publish in front end of main site.

These three sub sites must have 3 different admins who have the rights to change contents of their respective sites. Once this is done, all activities should be managed by main sites admin user who is super admin.

e.g.

My main site url is http://www.drupalmain.com. It has admin user whose name is admin_main.

Under this main site I want to create three sub sites like

- www.drupalmain.com/first  has admin user admin_sub1
- www.drupalmain.com/second  has admin user admin_sub2
- www.drupalmain.com/third  has admin user admin_sub3

And also these three admin should has restriction for content edit that means nobody can edit content of other users link.

Comment: Have you try it with domain module !!

Comment: have you read this article "Configuring Drupal for multi site with same domain using sub directory" http://drupal.org/node/1001080 ? M.

Comment: that content is Deprecated

Comment: Here is a great video. http://gotdrupal.com/videos/multisites-vs-multiple-sites